# Word for "unable to be bought"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a paper which includes some analysis of the fact that love cannot be bought. Repeating "cannot be bought" is becoming banal and repetitive, and I was wondering if there is a suitable replacement for it.

Comment: I don't suppose *unbuyable* would be suitable?

Comment: or, "not for sale"

Comment: 'priceless'....

Comment: I actually considered unbuyable, but I don't believe it's a valid word-according to word's spell check anyway.

Comment: Considering that *buy* is a “valid word”, and both *-able* and *-un* are productive affixes, it necessarily follows that the result of applying them must also be “valid words”.  Whatever that means.  Never ever ever trust Microsoft for anything.

Comment: When Word gives squiggly lines, try [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/unbuyable).  P.S. If _unbuyable_ gets tired, [_unpurchasable_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/unpurchasable) might work, too.

Comment: This is actually an economics question - there's a jargon term for precisely this concept. I can't remember it off the top of my head though.

Comment: @OptimalCynic Are you perhaps thinking of ***fungible***? “When a thing which is the subject of an obligation‥must be delivered in specie, the thing is not fungible, i.e. that very thing, and not another thing of the same or another class in lieu of it must be delivered. Where the subject of the obligation is *a* thing of a given class, the thing is said to be fungible, i.e. the delivery of any object which answers to the generic description will satisfy the terms of the obligation.” from John Austin’s *Lectures on Jurisprudence*,  3ʳᵈ ed., 1869;  II. xlvi. 807.

Comment: No, a fungible commodity can be bought - oil is fungible.

Answer (score 3):

Love is infungible.

That doesn't mean you can't buy it. Everyone knows that you can. You just can't exchange it.

Comment: Cynicism?! That's *reality*, man.

Comment: Just curious what motivates you to use *infungible* there instead of *unfungible*  or *nonfungible*. The OED doesn’t have any of them, but [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unfungible%2Cinfungible%2Cnon-fungible%2Cnonfungible&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) likes the last one.

Comment: You are correct. *Infungible* is Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

The words to express this idea are **invaluable** or **priceless**.

> That cannot have a value set upon it

Comment: That has too much connotational baggage. Misery can't be bought either, but very few people would call it invaluable.

Comment: @OptimalCynic: It does not mean "unable to be bought", but in the context of the OP, it could be used to describe love.

Comment: The OP's question was for a term that means "cannot be bought". Invaluable doesn't mean that, any more than inflammable means not flammable. The joys of English. Note that priceless and valueless are effectively antonyms, despite meaning the same thing by your definition.

Answer (score 0):

*Unavailable* has wider application, but I think it would be understood in context as describing what you have in mind.